# Is it safe to use a wildcard SSL certificate with regards to IE/XP support?

Tags: iis, ssl, https, sni

We want to create 'whitelabel' sites by having multiple hostnames pointing to the same IP (and website in IIS) and dynamically switching the site's database according to the hostname the user came in on.

eg. **https**://*co1*.mysite.com, *co2*.mysite.com and *co3*.mysite.com will all point to the same site, but in the site's code, we may change database connection strings and logos etc depending on what hostname they came in on.

In this particular context (with all sites going to the same IP) am I right in presuming that SNI doesn't come into play and as as long as a wildcard certificate is used (*.mysite.com) then all browsers will be able to access the site OK? **Even those with no SNI support** (eg Internet Explorer on Windows XP)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. Server will send the same cert for every request (even from SNI-capable clients). Of course you can't host there any other hostnames outside of scope of your wildcard cert, if all of them needs to be accessible from non-SNI clients.